# Getting two different results using ForEach in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have list of `structs` that I display in the view using a `ForEach`, I am trying to add to the list and when the user taps they see information for that item. Using two approaches I get two different results.

**First Approach**

The view updates the view when items are added perfectly, but changing the `note` in the Details changes values of all notes.

```
@Binding var person: Person

ForEach(self.person.notes) {
       note in
        DetailsCard(person: self.$person, note: notes)
}
```

**Second Approach**

The view does not update when notes are added, only when the view reappears does it show the new items. But I when the items are shown, the details view works as expected.

```
@Binding var person: Person

ForEach(self.person.notes.indices) { index in
     VStack {
        DetailsCard(person: self.$person, note: self.person.notes[index])
     }
}
```

**DetailView**

```
@Binding var person: Person
@State var note: Note
```

This should be a fairly simple task but working with SwiftUI I am confused by the two different results for similar approaches. Does anyone have any ideas on why this is occurring and how to correctly dynamically update the view and pass the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using dynamic `ForEach` loops, ie. with an explicit `id` parameter:

```
ForEach(self.person.notes, id:\.self)
```

```
ForEach(self.person.notes.indices, id:\.self)
```

Note: `id` must conform to `Hashable`. If you decide to use `self` as an `id`, it will only work if your item conforms to `Hashable`. Otherwise you may want to use some property (or just add the conformance).